# C# - iMZ320 serial port doesn't exist message

Tags: c#, printing, bluetooth

We have a program that communicate with Zebra printers on Serial Port. This program runs on WM devices (Motorola ES400, MC35, MC55 and MC65), and with MZ320 is very reliable but not with iMZ320. On the devices we use Bluetooth outgoing port. On iMZ320 the program throws very often an i/o exception. (Serial port doesn’t exist). The port is checked with GetPortNames before open and the COM port appears in the list.

Before the error message appears the program waits 80 seconds. (But only on ES400). The printer shows that the bluetooth connection is open (blue LED) during this time. If the printer is off we get the same message but after only 6 seconds. After this happens, the program on ES400 can not communicate with iMZ until we restart the printer. On MC55 the program waits 6 seconds, throws an exception, and after that we can print without restart.

The Zebra iMZ320 runs with the latest firmware.

In Zebra’s Multiplatform SDK there is a Demo. We tried this but got the same error.

Question: Does anybody have an idea why is it happening and what can we do?